# check a vector and output a singular TRUE or FALSE value

Tags: r, boolean, duplicates

I am checking for duplicate dates in a data set with the following command:

```
duplicateTest <- duplicated(index(closePricesClean))
```

The output for this is a "FALSE" for every date not duplicated. So, if closePricesClean has 500 observations, then duplicateTest will return a list of 500 "TRUE" or "FALSE" values. What I'd like instead is to return a single "FALSE" value if the entire vector is "FALSE" or "TRUE" if the list contains even one "TRUE" value.

Do I need to construct an if statement? Or is there a function that I don't know about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `anyDuplicated` and check whether or not its result equals zero.  This will be faster than using `any` on the results of `duplicated` because it will stop as soon as the first `TRUE` is encountered.

```
duplicateTest <- anyDuplicated(index(closePricesClean)) != 0
```

Answer (score 4):

`any` is what you are looking for. From the help:
Given a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true?

```
any(duplicateTest)
```